# If $G$ is a finite group can and $H$ is subgroup of $G$ then is it possible to take $G$ as sample space and $H$ as an event of $G$?

Tags: probability, abstract-algebra, group-theory

My work as $G$ is a group that means it is an algebraic structure $(G,*)$ where $G$ is a finite set and $*$ is an operation. And we know in probability sample space $S$ is a set of all outcome of a random experiment. So both $G$ and $S$ are finite set. So is it possible to say $G$ is a sample space. And $H$ is subgroup of $G$ so $H$ must be subset of $G$. We know event is subset of sample space. So is it possible to say subgroup $H$ as an event?

Comment: Yes, seems fine

Comment: You can say whatever you want and name things however you want. Whether this is useful and brings something substantial to the topic is a different question. For example I don't see how exactly you connect group theory and probability here. Except that both are sets. That's not a strong connection, since deep down everything in maths is a set (well, except for classes of course).

Comment: Can I use the property of conditional probability by taking group G is a sample space.and subgroup H as event of G.is it possible??? If not then why??

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly reasonable to consider $G$ as a sample space, and ask for the probability that a randomly chosen element lies in $H \leq G$.

To respond to the implicit question in the comments, there are indeed cases where this line of reasoning is interesting. As an example, let $H = Z$ be the center of $G$. That is, $Z = \{ x \in G ~|~ \forall y \in G . xy = yx \}$. It is a theorem (due to Erdos and Turan, iirc) that if $\Pr[xy = yx] > 5/8$ then $G$ is already abelian.

In light of this theorem, it seems natural to ask what we can say if we know, for example, $\Pr[x \in Z] > 5/8$ instead.

---

As for the followup question in the comments, it is *also* possible to use $H$ for conditional probabilities. As an example, if $K$ and $H$ are subgroups of $G$, then it is reasonable to ask $\Pr[x \in K ~|~ x \in H]$. I don't have any snappy justification for why this might be an interesting question, but I'm sure it's something somebody has considered.

In general, a group is a set with bonus properties. Any probabilistic question you might ask of a finite set is also a question you can ask of a finite group.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Let G be a group of order pq , H is a subgroup of order p and K is another subgroup of order q where p and q are relatively prime.
o(H)=p     and   o(K)=q
We know that H∩K is a subgroup of H and K science it contains the elements of both H and K.
Let g=o(H∩K) 

Hence    H∩K={e} , where e be the identity element of G.[3]
o(H∩K)=1


 p(H∩K)=(o(H∩K))/(O(G))  
        =1/pq
 p(K)=(o(K))/(o(G))=q/pq=1/P
Therefor
                 p(H│K)=P(H∩K)/P(K)   =(1/pq)/(1/p)=1/q , IS IT  CORRECT??

Comment: Please be careful about YELLING questions at people in the comments - it comes across as rude. I answered the question you asked and I think this new question would best be asked as a new question. That said, since you took the time to ask it here, yes. IT IS CORRECT.